# Windows Server 2008 R2: Syncing Primary Domain Controller to Internet Time (MS time server) error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, time-synchronization

Using a Microsoft resources to sync my PDC to microsoft's time I used the following command as an administerator on cmd

`w32tm /config /computer:<<PDC-FQDN>> /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /syncfromflags:manual /update`

but this returns `<< was unexpected at this time` what can I do to solve this and sync my pdc to Microsoft Time servers to avoid any further hickups

EDIT: how do i substitue `<<PDC-FQDN>>?` I typed the name of my domain controller-domain name but that didn't work

Comment: If you wanted to you could post your answer as an answer and then accept it with the exact command you used.

Comment: done that, maybe someone new to windows server will face this problem someday and will come across this solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solved it, was just a matter of syntax, this is the default command from the microsoft site.

`w32tm /config /computer:<<PDC-FQDN>> /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /syncfromflags:manual /update`

In order for it to execute you have to get rid of the `"<< >>"` and enter the name of you PDC with the domain name like "servername.domainname"

So suppose you server name *(PDC name)* is: `mynewdomaincontroller1`
and your domain name is: `twinkles.com`

Then this is how you will write the command:
`w32tm /config /computer:mynewdomaincontroller1.twinkles.com /manualpeerlist:time.windows.com /syncfromflags:manual /update`